# How to convert this TSQL into Linq Method approach

Tags: sql, linq

We have this T-SQL query:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 
    AtheleteName, SUM(RankingScore) AS RankingScore
FROM
    [dbo].[TournamentBatchItem]
WHERE
    Gender = 'Male'
GROUP BY
    AtheleteName, Gender
ORDER BY 
    SUM(RankingScore) DESC
```

So far attempted below but not even close. The ordering is not there. Any ideas?

```cs
var top20ScoreMale = await _context.TournamentBatchItem
                                   .Where(t => t.Gender == "Male")
                                   .GroupBy( t => t.AtheleteName)
                                   .Select(t => new Stat2 { Name = t.Key, Value = t.Sum(i => i.RankingScore) })
                                   .Take(10)
                                   .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You haven't included any ordering something like .OrderByDescending(Stat2)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to order the results descending by their `Value` before taking the top 10

```
var top10ScoreMale = await _context.TournamentBatchItem
                                .Where(t => t.Gender == "Male")
                                .GroupBy(t => t.AtheleteName)
                                .Select(g => new Stat2 { 
                                    Name = g.Key, 
                                    Value = g.Sum(x => x.RankingScore) 
                                })
                                .OrderByDescending(_ => _.Value)
                                .Take(10)
                                .ToListAsync();
```